# Showing email address as hint

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

I have seen Mail services displays the email id's as `e*****e@gmail.com` , mostly in their recovery page.

So  i am trying to replace the `example@gmail.com` as `e*****e@gmail.com` .

Is it possible to achieve it using [`String#replace(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) alone ? or should i use some REGEX to achieve it .

Thanks for your valuable suggestions in adavance

Comment: @SanKrish are you trying to replace the exact number of chars with exact number of `*`? What would be the output for `fooooooooooooob@gnail.com` ?

Comment: @AvinashRaj it will be like `f****b@g***l.com` . i dont need the exact number of characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search regex:

```
\b(\w)\S*?(\S)(?=@)(\S+)\b
```

Replacement Pattern:

```
$1****$2$3****$4
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/jY9fJ4/2)

**Code:**

```
String email = "anexample@gmail.com"; 
String repl = email.replaceFirst("\\b(\\w)\\S*?(\\S@)(\\S)\\S*(\\S\\.\\S*)\\b", 
      "$1****$2$3****$4");
//=> a****e@g****l.com
```

Comment: Will this work if there's a period in the first part of the email address, though?

Comment: Didn't get your comment, what characters you want to escape? Can you tell input and expected output?

Comment: Oh I forgot the quotes around `"$1****$2$3****$4"`. See updated one

Comment: one more update, problem was dot was not doubly escaped. Try now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63096/discussion-between-san-krish-and-anubhava).

Comment: I have found this site: http://www.regular-expressions.info/ one of the best to learn regex.

Answer (score 2):

It could be possible through replaceAll function.

```
(?<!^).(?=.*?.@)
```

Use the above regex and replace the matched characters with `*`

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/jC4qF9/7)

```
String s = "example@gmail.com";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(?<!^).(?=.*?.@)", "*"));
```

**Output:**

```
e*****e@gmail.com
```

**Update:**

Use the below regex to get the output like `e*****e@g***l.com`

```
String s = "example@gmail.com";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\\B.\\B(?=.*?\\.)", "*"));
```

**Output:**

```
e*****e@g***l.com
```

Comment: thanks for your answer . but it doesnt work if the email id contains `.` like `a.user@gmail.com`

Comment: Thank you :) is it even good for the beginners , i mean to learn from scratch ?

Comment: Yes :) Hope you are also :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try without regex too

```
 String email = "example@gmail.com";
 int start = 1;
 int end = email.indexOf("@") - 1;
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(email);
 StringBuilder sb1=new StringBuilder();
 for(int i=start;i<end;i++){
    sb1.append("*");
 }
 sb.replace(start, end, sb1.toString());
 System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Out put:

```
 e*****e@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 1):

I sugges to use `indexOf` and `substring`. With replace you can run into tuble with emails like `gmail@gmail.com`